# Understanding heatmap dendogram clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap

I would appreciate any info material on the dendograms (Colv, Rowv) of R's heatmap function. Such as how the clustering works (is it euclidean distance?). You don't have to post lengthy explanations, I would already be happy about some keywords that could bring me on the right track so I could do some online research.

Here is an excerpt from the help manual, which confuses me a little bit. What does "honored" mean in this context and how is it different from reordering?

> If either Rowv or Colv are dendrograms they are honored (and not
>   reordered).

Comment: It just means that you can either supply your own dendrograms (passed in Rowv and/or Colv) or you can let heatmap calculate dendrograms for you. So 'honored' just means that if you supply your own dendrogram, heatmap will 'honor' them, i.e. use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rowv` and `Colv` control whether the rows and columns of your data set should be reordered and if so how.

The possible values for them are `TRUE`, `NULL`, `FALSE`, a vector of integers, or a dendrogram object.

- In the default mode `TRUE`, heatmap.2 performs clustering using the `hclustfun` and `distfun` parameters. This defaults to complete linkage clustering, using a euclidean distance measure. The dendrogram is then reordered using the row/column means. You can control this by specifying different functions to `hclustfun` or `distfun`. For example to use the Manhattan distance rather than the euclidiean distance you would do:

  ```
  heatmap.2(x,...,distfun=function (y) dist(y,method = "manhattan") )
  ```

  check out `?dist` and `?hclust`. If you want to learn more about clustering you could start with "distance measures" and "agglomeration methods".
- If `Rowv`/`Colv` is `NULL` or `FALSE` then no reordering or clustering is done and the matrix is plotted as-is.
- If `Rowv`/`Colv` is a numeric vector, then the clustering is computed as for `TRUE` and the reordering of the dendrogram is done using the vector supplied to `Rowv`/`Colv`.
- If `Rowv`/`Colv` is a dendrogram object, then this dendrogram will be used to reorder the matrix. Dendrogram objects can be generated, for example, by:

  ```
  rowDistance = dist(x, method = "manhattan")
  rowCluster = hclust(rowDistance, method = "complete")
  rowDend = as.dendrogram(rowCluster)
  rowDend = reorder(rowDend, rowMeans(x))
  ```

  which generates a complete clustering on a manhattan distance, ordered by row means. You can now pass `rowDend` to `Rowv`.

  ```
  heatmap.2(x,...,Rowv = rowDend)
  ```

  This can be useful, if for example you want to cluster the rows and columns in different ways, or use a clustering that someone else has given you, or you want to do something funky that cannot be accommodated by just specifying the hclustfun and the distfun. This is what is meant by" the dendrogram is honoured": it is used instead of what is specified by hclustfun and distfun.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I find the behavior of heatmap() vs. heatmap.2() a little bit confusing. To me it seems that in heatmap.2 Rowv=TRUE is the default, and in heatmap() Rowv=NULL is the default. But both default options are calculating complete linkage clustering based in euclidean distances?

Comment: Yes. Rowv=NULL in heatmap is equivalent to Rowv=TRUE in heatmap.2. In both cases complete linkage clustering based on euclidean distance is the default clustering because this is Rs default clustering mode independent of any function that is being used to plot the results.

Answer (score 2):

To look into how it handles Rowv/Colv exactly, you might also use `body(heatmap)` to display its source.

Comment: Thanks, body is a new function to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> distfun    : function used to compute the distance (dissimilarity) between
>   both rows and columns. Defaults to dist.
>
> hclustfun  : function used to compute the hierarchical clustering when
>   Rowv or Colv are not dendrograms. Defaults to hclust. Should take as
>   argument a result of distfun and return an object to which
>   as.dendrogram can be applied.

`dist()` has as default the euclidean distance and `hclust()` the complete linkage method.

Comment: `If either Rowv or Colv are dendrograms they are honored (and not reordered). Otherwise, dendrograms are computed as dd <- as.dendrogram(hclustfun(distfun(X))) where X is either x or t(x).` I am still confused: When I not set Colv=NA and Rowv=NA will it be the euclidean distance or the complete linkage method? Because the as.dendrogram invokes both hclustfun and distfun if I understand correctly

Comment: Not 'or' it is 'and'! Complete Linkage Clustering on the matrix of eclidean distances. I suggest you to read a little bit on Hierarchical Clustering.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do that! EDIT: Am I on the right track with the hierarchical agglomerate clustering?