# Reordering dendrogram in a heatmap using library(NMF) in R

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram, nmf

I have a dataframe like so:

```
set.seed(123)    
test_df<-data.frame(Sample=c(LETTERS),var1=rnorm(26),var2=rnorm(26),color=rep(sample(c("High","low"),26,replace=TRUE)))
```

I can generate a dendrogram from it using `library(dendextend)`:

```
d<-dist(scale(test_df[,2:3]))
clust<-hclust(d)%>%as.dendrogram()
```

I want to use this dendrogram `clust` to order the samples in another dataframe. This dataframe has the same samples and looks like:

```
test_df_extend<-data.frame(Sample=c(LETTERS),var1=rnorm(26),var2=rnorm(26),var3=rnorm(26),var4=rnorm(26),var5=rnorm(26),var6=rnorm(26),color=rep(c("High","low"),13))
```

I can generate the heatmap for `test_df_extend` using the following code:

```
row.names(test_df_extend)<-test_df_extend$Sample
aheatmap(as.matrix(test_df_extend[,2:7]), color = "-RdBu:50", scale = "col", breaks = 0,Colv = NA,annColors = c("rainbow"),annRow=test_df_extend[,8])
```

However when I am trying to pass the dendrogram `clust` into aheatmap I am having problems comprehending the output.  I can get a reordered dendrogram but unsure what the difference between 1) and 2) below means. One has `Rowv` specified and the other has `reorderfun` specified with a random `w` !?. I guess I don't fully understand the `reorderfun` arguments specially the weight (w) argument and its relationship to `Rowv`. Can anyone help me with an explanation? Thanks!

1)

```
aheatmap(as.matrix(test_df_extend[,2:7]), color = "-RdBu:50", scale = "col", breaks = 0,Colv = NA,annColors = c("rainbow"),annRow=test_df_extend[,8],Rowv=clust)
```

2)

```
aheatmap(as.matrix(test_df_extend[,2:7]), color = "-RdBu:50", scale = "col", breaks = 0,Colv = NA,annColors = c("rainbow"),annRow=test_df_extend[,8], reorderfun=function(d,w) reorder(clust,1))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the dendextend R package?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#gplots

Comment: @TalGalili Yes ..thanks for the package ..it has been immensely helpful.  I had to use the rotate function to get the proper order I needed.  I have recently started using it a lot. as you can see from the unnecessary as.dendrogam from dendextend in the question. For  the heatmap, I got a better understanding of Rowv from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388082/understanding-heatmap-dendogram-clustering-in-r  but still do not have a good intuition for the reorder function.